# Multiple transitions with scss

Tags: css, sass, vendor-prefix

I have a multiple transition problem with scss `@mixin`.
Im trying to create dynamic transition `@mixin` with **1-5** different properties. When I'm processing the code below this **error shows up**:

> Error: Mixin transition takes 1 argument but 3 were passed.
>           on line 758 of style.scss, in `transition'
>           from line 758 of style.scss   Use --trace for backtrace.

**This is my code:**

---

**@mixin:**

```
@mixin transition($x){
    transition: $x;
    -webkit-transition: $x;
    -moz-transition: $x;
    -ms-transition: $x;
    -o-transition: $x;
}
```

---

**@include:**

```
@include transition(visibility 0s ease 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease, transform 0.3s ease);
```

---

I figured it out with this hack but it looks like a very unclean solution to me:

```
@include transition(visibility 0s ease 0.2s + "," + opacity 0.2s ease + "," + transform 0.3s ease);
```

**Is there a better way to do it?**

Comment: Without comma if a remember correctly

Comment: You don't need to vendor-prefix `transition` these days anyway.

Comment: In cases where you do need to prefix, use a competent prefixer such as [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer).

Comment: Sounds like a dumb suggestion, but out the top of my head - can't you just put double quotes around the whole argument like so: @include transition("visibility 0s ease 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease, transform 0.3s ease"); I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure this would work;

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your `mixin`, you have declared a single variable `$x` as a parameter which means that sass expects the `mixin` to be called with one argument.

`@include transition(visibility 0s ease 0.2s)`

When you pass the mixin comma separated values, it causes an error because sass sees these as multiple values instead of a single value which it expects.

`@include transition(visibility 0s ease 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease) //Sees two args instead of one arg`

In Sass, comma separated values can be interpreted as a single value if declared as *varargs*. *Varargs* are mixin or function parameters declared with 3 dots appended to their name.

Replacing your `$x` parameter with `$x...` will ensure that sass interprets the comma separated arguments passed to your mixin as *one value*.

```
@mixin transition($x...){
  -webkit-transition: $x;
  -moz-transition: $x;
  -ms-transition: $x;
  -o-transition: $x;
  transition: $x;
}
```

It can then be used like this

```
div {
  @include transition(color 1s, background-color 1s, border-color 1s);
}
```

which compiles to

```
div {
  -webkit-transition: color 1s, background-color 1s, border-color 1s;
  -moz-transition: color 1s, background-color 1s, border-color 1s;
  -ms-transition: color 1s, background-color 1s, border-color 1s;
  -o-transition: color 1s, background-color 1s, border-color 1s;
  transition: color 1s, background-color 1s, border-color 1s;
}
```

By doing this you can pass the values as you normally would in CSS without the hack you are currently using making it much cleaner.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me out

Answer (score 6):

Since this is the first result on Google, I want to say that this does not solve my problem. I wanted to transition *multiple properties*, with only one mixin. I came up with [this](https://gist.github.com/yspreen/8e1b4e51d2e90a298ee0041577250410) solution: (see link for helper functions)

```
/*
  usage: @include transition(prop1, prop2, ..., 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.85, 0.45, 1));
*/
@mixin transition($args...) {
  $type: nth($args, length($args));
  $props: remove-nth($args, length($args));
  $result: ();

  @for $i from 1 through length($props) {
    $prop: nth($props, $i);
    $result: append($result, $prop);
    $result: append($result, $type);
    @if $i != length($props) {
      $result: append($result, unquote($string: ","));
    }
  }

  @include simple_transition($result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a short mixin that allows adding multiple transition properties in one declaration. In case number of arguments provided for the timing, easing or delay, is less than number of transition properties, the arguments are repeated.

```
@mixin transition($prop, $time, $easing: $ease1, $delay: 0s) {
    $transition: ();
    @for $i from 1 through length($prop) {
        @for $j from 0 to (length($prop)) - (length($time)) {
            $time: join($time, nth($time, -1));
        }
        @for $j from 0 to (length($prop)) - (length($easing)) {
            $easing: join($easing, nth($easing, -1));
        }
        @for $j from 0 to (length($prop)) - (length($delay)) {
            $delay: join($delay, nth($delay, -1));
        }

        $transition: append(
            $transition,
            (nth($prop, $i) nth($time, $i) nth($easing, $i) nth($delay, $i)),
            $separator: comma
        );
    }
    transition: $transition;
}

//scss input:
@include transition(height width transform, 0.2s 0.3s, linear, 0s);

//css output:
transition: height 0.2s linear 0s, width 0.3s linear 0s, transform 0.3s linear 0s;
```

Answer (score 3):

Where time and easing are the same, but with **multiple properties**:

```
@mixin transitionPrefixMultiple($time, $properties...) {
  $transition: ();
  @each $property in $properties {
    $transition: append(
        $transition, ($property $time cubic-bezier(.42, 0, .58, 1)), $separator: comma
    );
  }
  -webkit-transition: $transition;
     -moz-transition: $transition;
      -ms-transition: $transition;
       -o-transition: $transition;
          transition: $transition;
}
```

Usage:

```
@include transitionPrefixMultiple(150ms, width, background-color, etc);
```

Thank you @nidhishs06 as this is a cleaner version of your answer